# Giving a priority of network traffic for one application over the other; in practice (windows)

Tags: networking, traffic, traffic-shaping

Two applications perform network i/o concurrently.
For instance, Firefox and Download Accelerator.

The idea is to let serve the queue of packets of Firefox prior to serving those of Download Accelerator. (Well, almost all the time — allow a portion of those of Download Accelerator to come through in order to avoid breaking the connections)

It is no problem to configure them both to use a local proxy (maybe with different credentials).

Which local proxy, a firewall or ... you name it ... can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give this one a try:
[Traffic Shaper](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html)

It looks like it would work for what you are wanting to do. Also has some good tutorials on the site if you are not familiar with setting up firewalls.

Answer (score 2):

I think the magic phrase you want to google is "traffic shaping".

It is possible to build a shaper with Linux and iptables, or you can spend appropriately large amounts of money to buy an appliance (for example from Packeteer) to do the job for you.